# Telerik Grid - BindTo, DataBinding

Tags: telerik

What is the use of BindTo() and DataBinding() properties of Telerik Grid Control.
Without using these two properties we can bind the Telerik Grid and we can display the records.
So I would like to know how to use these two properties to bind telerik Grid and what is the advantage of using these type of bindings.

In Telerik demo I have seen two properties for DataBinding()
Ajax() and Server() - What is the use of these two properties?

Answer (score 0):

By using DataBinding method we can bind data dynamically.
In ASP.net MVC If you use like below then during data binding the action will call from mentioned controller and action will return the data that will bind to grid.
For search functionality DataBinding method is very useful.

```
.DataBinding(dataBinding => dataBinding.Ajax().Select("ActionName", "Controller"))
```

Answer (score 0):

[This tutorial](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/telerik-ui-components-grid-data-binding-ajax-binding.html) explains the difference between server and Ajax binding, and provides good instructions on accomplishing ajax binding.

Answer (score 0):

Basically **Ajax** is using Ajax requests when you page/sort/group/filter also Ajax request when you add/update/delete records.

In **Server** mode each operation is doing a GET or POST request to the server and it refreshes the whole page. However when using server binding you have better search indexing (like google etc) you can give url-s which represent the current Grid set.
Check the demos and you will see the difference.
When using Ajax you have better performance (less server loading) for sure!